# How do i customize the list view web part?

Tags: list-view-web-part

I am displaying a custom list using a ListViewWebPart.  I want to update the display so that it has some buttons (two columns at the end with buttons).

I then want to handle the button click and do some custom logic.

Can i do this with the ListViewWebPart?

I am using the correct web part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the dataview webpart rather than the list view one.  Insert a blank dataview in sharepoint designer and then attach the custom list as the data source.  You can do a lot more with the dataview webpart than the list view one.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is put HTML through calculated column following the link below:
[Using calculated columns to write HTML](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/using-calculated-columns-to-write-html/)

The guy has explained how you can add HTML in a calculated column or you can make single line textbox to prepare your HTML and then using JavaScript the HTML will be rendered in XSLTListView.. following is the link to download JavaScript:
[Download link - Topic : HTML Calculated Column](http://pathtosharepoint.com/Downloads/Forms/AllItems.aspx)

So you can create buttons, link buttons, image buttons inside and on javascript redirect to other page or call pop up etc.

But you need to make sure the JavaScript is on every page you have the XSLTListView...

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You would open the page in SharePoint Designer and modify the Web Part by adding the buttons. Custom logic when pressing the buttons would be easiest by using JavaScript and Client Object Model.

Comment: what about changing this to use a SPGridView?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution using JSLink.

https://sharepointatwork.wordpress.com/2015/05/09/add-followunfollow-button-in-listview-webparts-for-document-libraries-using-jslink/